# reading multi line cells using openpyxl

Tags: python-2.7

I'm using openpyxl module to read data from an .xlsx file. I have a cell that contains multiples lines and I would like to know if it's possible to print only the value of the second line.

[image]

I'm using `print sheet.cell(row=6, column=2).value` but its printing all the lines.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard string processing in Python:

```
text = sheet.cell(row=6, column=2).value
lines = text.splitlines()
print(lines[1])
```